# Calling interface method, but return type is not valid?

Tags: java

I hate to come one here and ask what is probably a stupid question, but I'm a coding student and my teacher has offered very little information on the subject of interfaces but I have an assignment due, and I'm having a problem calling a method within an interface that a class is implementing. Here is the code of the project I am making

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2B {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Octagon test = new Octagon();
      System.out.printf("The octagon has a side length of %1.2f, a perimiter of %1.2f, and an area of %1.2f.", test.sideLength, test.perimiter, test.area);
   }
}

abstract class GeometricObject {
   double area;
   double perimiter;
   public GeometricObject() {

   }
}

class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable, Cloneable {
   double sideLength;
   public Octagon() {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter side length of Octagon: ");
      this.sideLength = input.nextDouble();
      this.area = ((2 + (4 / Math.sqrt(2))) * this.sideLength * this.sideLength);
      this.perimiter = (this.sideLength * 8);
   }

   public void clone() {
   System.out.println("I wish I knew how to code");
   }
}


interface Cloneable {
   public void clone();
}
```

and its giving me this error

```
Lab2B.java:29: error: clone() in Octagon cannot override clone() in Object
public void clone() {
            ^
return type void is not compatible with Object
```

I'm honestly not sure what I am doing wrong here, this seems to be in line with every example of an interface that I can find on the internet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: implements `Cloneable`

Comment: Why do you have  your own `Cloneable` interface?

Comment: I really have no idea what I am doing so I don't even know what I am doing wrong by having my own `Cloneable` interface.

Comment: Does the assignment require you to `implement Cloneable`? If not, I suggest you remove this.

Comment: Unfortunately it does, but this is not something that any of our class materials have covered so I guess I'm on my own to figure out how it use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can implement Cloneable interface from java( no need to create your own).

Also, its a bit weird but clone method is in Object class which needs to be overriden. (It should have been in Cloneable). To override clone method, you can do something like this:

```
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

}
```

Here is a good read on Deep and Shallow Copy using clone:

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

First you should not declare a `Cloneable` interface. This already exists in the standard Java API.

However, unless implementing `Cloneable` is specifically required by your assignment, you should remove it from your code. The `Cloneable` interface's design is considered broken by modern Java standards. It only exists because of legacy code that was written when Java was first invented.